# How can I add labels when specifying relationships using x->y->z notation?

Tags: graphviz, dot

Is there a way to add individual labels when you specify a graph using the following format?

```
digraph {
    1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean labels on nodes, it can be done like this:

```
digraph { 
    1 [label="A"]
    2 [label="B"]
    3 [label="C"]
    1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 1 
 }
```

If you want to label the edges, you have to split them up like this:

```
digraph { 
    1 -> 2 [label="A"]
    2 -> 3 [label="B"]
    3 -> 1 [label="C"]
}
```

The reason you cannot do something like `1 -> 2 [label="x"] -> 3 [label="y"]...` can be found in the [dot specification](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language):

```
attr_list   :   '[' [ a_list ] ']' [ attr_list ]
a_list  :   ID [ '=' ID ] [ ',' ] [ a_list ]
edge_stmt   :   (node_id | subgraph) edgeRHS [ attr_list ]
edgeRHS     :   edgeop (node_id | subgraph) [ edgeRHS ]
```

Each `edge_stmt` can have only one `attr_list`.

Comment: There's one interesting case: if a node links to several nodes, and all those edges share the same label, you can do this: `1 -> {2;3;} [label="abc"]`